# Getting last appearance of a deeply nested value by specified property

Tags: javascript

I've got this object as example:

```
const obj = {
    group: {
        data: {
            data: [
                {
                    id: null,
                    value: 'someValue',
                    data: 'someData'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

My goal is to get a value by propery name.

In this case I would like to get
the value of the `data` propery, but the **last** appearance of it.

Meaning the expected output is:

```
someData
```

However, I'm using this recursive function to retreive it:

```
const findVal = (obj, propertyToExtract) => {
  if (obj && obj[propertyToExtract]) return obj[propertyToExtract];

  for (let key in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          const value = findVal(obj[key], propertyToExtract);
          if (value) return value;
      }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Which gives me the **first** appearance of `data`, meaning:

```
data: [
    {
       value: 'someValue',
       data: 'someData'
    }
]
```

How can I get the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way can be to recursively flat the object and just get the wanted index (here data)

```js
const obj = {
group: {
    data: {
        data: [
            {
                id: null,
                value: 'someValue',
                data: 'someData'
            }
        ]
    }
}
};

function deepFlat(obj) {
  let flatObj = {};
  flat(obj,flatObj);
  console.log(flatObj);
  return flatObj;
}

function flat(toFlat, flatObj) {
  Object.entries(toFlat).forEach(elem => {
    if (elem[1] && typeof elem[1] === 'object') {
     flat(elem[1], flatObj);
    } else {
      flatObj[elem[0]] = elem[1];
    }
  });
}

let result = deepFlat(obj);
console.log(result['data']);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was off work. Your answer is appreciated.
Anyhow, in some objects I pass I get this error: 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'. 
How can I integrate a fix to that?

Comment: The issue persists. I've edited my example object above to simlate the situation it happens, which is when one of the nested values is `null`  (`undefined` works even though it's mentioned in the error message)

Comment: i add a security to test if elem is an object to allow null data 
    ``if (elem[1] && typeof elem[1] === 'object') {``